# Loading a WebView URL before splashscreen finishes

Tags: javascript, android, imageview, android-webview

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QD9nhyWX-gs to make an animated splashscreen which is just my logo doing one 360˚ spin which text and a background below it after the spin it opens a webview which displays google.com.au but it has that white background while it loads the webpage and i need it to load the webpage beforehand in the splashscreen and keep the animation repeating till the website it loaded, the code is fairly simple its just a rotating imageview.

Just tried:

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends Activity {
WebView web;
ImageView imageView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.voxelservers.net");
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

// To handle "Back" key press event for WebView to go back to previous screen.
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
        web.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Its just a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

One way we can achieve this is by rather than opening a new activity for webview,
In `WelcomeActivity.java` itself add webView and imageView to the layout and make webview to invisible or Gone.

On open of WelcomeActivity initialize webView and set custom `WebViewClient`. Override `onPageFinished()` in your Custom webViewClient and in this method make webview visible and imageView to Gone.

Comment: Will try that now , not the best with javascript so if i get something wrong ill post back here

Comment: 1. Where is your animation??
2. In onPageFinished() you are making imageView to Gone that is fine but make visibility of webView to visible, as shown below.

imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
web.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Fixed, Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Fresh Prince Glad to help you :)